# Delete data from sql after search with pdo all in one page

Tags: mysql, search, pdo, sql-delete

I have been trying to find out the magic code that allows to do search and most important delete data in my code. I put together all the search code and it works great, but when it comes to make it delete I get stuck I can't find the right place and code to make my data delete. I have look everywhere I have found in google.
My question its can any one solve this delete issue or it's not possible at the current technology? My code is shown below:

```html
<?php 
//load database connection
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "abcd";
    $password = "******";
    $database_name = "abcd";
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database_name", $user, $password, array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    ));
// Search from MySQL database table




$search=$_POST['search'];
$query = $pdo->prepare("select * from wfuk where post_code LIKE '%$search%' OR telephone LIKE '%$search%'  LIMIT 0 , 10");
$query->bindValue(1, "%$search%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
// Display search result
?>
<html>
<head>
<title> How To Create A Database Search With MySQL & PHP Script | Tutorial.World.Edu </title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="search.php" method="post">
Search: <input type="text" name="search" placeholder=" Search here ... "/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<?php
  if (!$query->rowCount() == 0) {
    echo "Search found :<br/>";
    echo "<table style=\"font-family:arial;color:#333333;\">";  
    echo "<tr>
    <td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;background:#98bf21;\">First Name</td>
    <td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;background:#98bf21;\">Last Name</td>
    <td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;background:#98bf21;\">Trade</td>
    <td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;background:#98bf21;\">Post Code</td>
    <td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;background:#98bf21;\">Telephone</td>
    <td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;background:#98bf21;\">Comments</td>
    <td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;background:#98bf21;\">To be use</td></tr>";            
   while ($results = $query->fetch()) {

    echo "<tr><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;\">";            
    echo $results['first_name'];

    echo "</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;\">";           
    echo $results['last_name'];

    echo "</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;\">";           
    echo $results['trade'];

    echo "</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;\">";           
    echo $results['post_code'];

    echo "</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;\">";
    echo $results['telephone'];

    echo "</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;\">";
    echo $results['comments'];

    echo "</td><td style=\"border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#98bf21;\">";
    echo("<button onclick=\"location.href='search.php?del=" . $results['id'] . "'\"> delete user</button>"); 

    echo "</td></tr>";              
     }
    echo "</table>";        
     } else {
    echo 'Nothing found';
     }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello the the delete option have to be done whit a delete page

```html
<?php
 require_once("db_reg.php");//this its the conection to the host
if (!isset($_POST['submit']));// comes from del <button onclick=\"location.href='search.php?del=" . $results['id'] . "'\">
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
 if (!$link)
{
die('Could NOT Connect: rong pass ' . mysql_error(rong_pass));
}
$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);
if (!$db_selected) 
{
die ('Cant\'t use' . DB_NAME. 'abcd' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'log in succes';
 if( isset($_GET['del']) ) // this its basicley the delet function
 {
  $id = $_GET['del'];
  $sql= "DELETE FROM construction WHERE id='$id'";
  $res= mysql_query($sql) or die("Failed".mysql_error());
  echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=search.php'>";
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The query you will need:

```
DELETE FROM wfuk 
WHERE id = ?
```

The value for id parameter would be the query string:

```
$query->bindValue(1, $_GET['del'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: ok but where i place them that its my issue , cause if i set another pdo whit delete from ... function will cancel de first one and i get a error . baseline i am asking you to complete the last part of this puzzle , cause i am brain death

Comment: you put that code in `search.php` thats where you passed the query string right, but if you want have a separate `delete.php` script that would do this

Comment: and that i was trying not to do to make it on one page perfect script . thx